# Read cross account table in glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-lambda, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a cross account table that is currently in my glue catalog and for the sake of understanding lets assume the database name is test_db and table name that shows in the glue catalog is abc.table_name

How do I read this table in my glue job using Gluecontext or spark?

Am not aware of how the table was populated in our Glue catalog and one of my collegue told that table is from a different account.

`    Tried reading the table

```
1)
spark.read.table("test_db"."abc.table_name")
spark.read.table("test_db".abc.table_name)
spark.read.table("test_db.abc.table_name")

Throws error expecting only 1 database name.

2) 
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="test_db", table_name="abc.table_name")

Throws error saying classification not defined.`
```